# HTTR GET new error: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: r, httr

I have been running this code for months without issue. Today I suddenly started receiving the following error message on both of my AWS servers:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

when trying to run the following code:

```
GET(url="myurl",authenticate("myusername","mypw"))
```

I tried uninstalling the HTTR package and reinstalling, but it did not work. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

After trying numerous R and OS package updates, I checked with the operator of the API I'm trying to pull from and confirmed that the issue is on their end.