# Webpage works in browser, but not from R: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: r, ssl, rvest, rcurl, jsonlite

[This](https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json) url works in the browser, providing some JSON data.

It worked from R until very recently, it now returns:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json")

# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
#   SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

library(rvest)
read_html("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json")

# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
#   SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

#### What I know so far

I am not sure if this is an issue on the API side, or somewhere in R?

- There seems to be an analogous solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295194/5783745), although any solution I use must not use browser automation (selenium), but instead must use either jsonlite or rvest

Comment: I can't replicate - both lines work fine. It doesn't seem to be the API. Maybe try a different connection method? Perhaps `read_html(url("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json", method= "libcurl"))`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks Allan. Can you say which version of R you're using? I am on 4.0.1

Comment: the PC I'm on at the moment is running an old version: 3.6.1

Comment: Interesting. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246994/how-do-i-resolve-this-rcurl-error-ssl-certificate-problem-certificate-has-exp) related question is also running R 4. But that may be coincidence.

Comment: Did you try different `method = ` to see if that fixed it Steve?

Comment: @AllanCameron I tried but get `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json'`

Comment: Possibly also related (the answer indicates that in that case it was a problem with the API): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57339291/5783745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who is having a similar issue

#### The Cause

The website owner had an expired SSL certificate.

I was able to confirm this via [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json) website:

[image]

#### (imperfect) Solution

Since I have no control over the url's SSL certificate, I simply changed all the urls I was using from `https` to `http`.

For example:

```
"https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json"
```

changes to

```
"http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the ssl settings in R with

```r
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE, ssl_verifyhost = FALSE))
```